# Why is it necessary to have a topology associated to a filtration of algebraic objects?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, filtrations

Why is it necessary that when we are defining a filtration of algebraic objects there must be a topology associated to the filtration?

For example, a descending filtration of group has the topology whose basis is the set of all translates of subgroups appearing in the filtration. Then for modules and ring there is I-adic topology. And so for other cases.

My question is-

Why is it necessary to have a topology associated to the filtration?

Does it come by default?

Please explain it.

Comment: What do you mean by "necessary"?

Comment: For a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ the homomorphism $\phi :R\to \varprojlim R/I^n$ is natural, no topology is needed. But $\varprojlim R/I^n$ is useful (in particular when $\phi $ is injective and $I$ is principal) mostly because we can represent its elements as series, the series convergent for the topology with basis of open sets $a+I^n$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I mean why there is a concept of topology associated to a filtration?